# Create Custom UITableViewCell Programmatically - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        //[self createViews];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"draw rect");
    [self createViews];
}
```

I'm creating a custom `UITableViewCell`. I require creating a UILabel that depends on the height of the `UITableViewCell`, and the height is not yet set in `initWithStyle` (it returns the default 44 when in reality the height of my cell varies greatly). For this reason, I call my `createViews` function in `drawRect`. This was working well, however I'm noticing that the function can be called again when I insert and delete rows.

**My Question:**
Does it make sense to call my `createViews` function inside `drawRect`?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing it in drawRect. How are you getting your cell height? Why not use auto layout and your cell doesn't need to worry about its height.

Comment: No. drawRect should not be used to create views.

Comment: @rmaddy where should I create my views then if I'm not using autolayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few options here.

**1.** Use layoutSubviews/awakeFromNib, check whether the subviews were created, if no, create them with correct frames.

**2.** Use init to create views with:

- Constraints
- Without constraints and in layoutSubviews/awakeFromNib try to change the frame